# Multiple titlepages in a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, titles

I will be giving a job talk using Beamer slides.
In my job talk, I will be presenting two papers.
I would like, therefore, to have three titlepages, in the format shown below.
The first titlepage is the real title page.
The second and third titlepages are to display the information about the papers from which that section of the talk is based.

```
\begin{frame}{}
Title of My Talk
My Name
The Date
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
Title of Paper 1
Names of Paper 1 Authors
\end{frame}

... slides for paper 1 ...

\begin{frame}{}
Title of Paper 2
Names of Paper 2 Authors
\end{frame}

... slides for paper 2 ...
```

Is it possible to do this in Beamer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unlike the titling commands in a regular article, the `beamer` versions can be issued anywhere in the document, and reassigned:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\title{A main title}
\author{Main Author}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\title{A secondary title}
\author{Main Author and others}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I didn't know about this. That's extremely neat!